# Error in JavaFX FXML tutorial

Tags: eclipse, oracle, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I have followed every step in this (https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to) tutorial, and yet keep getting an error about this section in the controller class:

```
    myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("That was easy, wasn't it?");
        }
    });
```

The only difference I can think of is that it was written for FX 2.0 and not 8.0?

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>) in the type ButtonBase is not applicable for the arguments (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){})
    EventHandler cannot be resolved to a type
    The method handle(ActionEvent) of type new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){} must override or implement a supertype method

    at simple.SimpleController.initialize(SimpleController.java:24)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at simple.Main.start(Main.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application simple.Main
```

Let me know if you need to see the classes and FXML files (dw, they're very short)

Thank you!

PS- Please bear with me if I need clarification about your answer because as a Java newbie I often get confused!

EDIT 1:

```
package simple;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class SimpleController
    implements Initializable {

    @FXML //  fx:id="myButton"
    private Button myButton; // Value injected by FXMLLoader


    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
        assert myButton != null : "fx:id=\"myButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'simple.fxml'.";

        // initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected
        myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("That was easy, wasn't it?");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: It says you have a compile error, with `EventHandler` not being recognized. Please post the `SimpleController` source code (including imports).

Comment: There are several classes named `EventHandler` and `ActionEvent`, show us which ones you are importing.

Comment: (I'm not sure if you get updated when I edit the question so here! notification!) Thank you so much for looking at this I'm very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the import for `EventHandler`, and you have the wrong import for `ActionEvent`. (Also you have imported `ActionListener` for some reason, though you never use it.)

Your imports should be

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
```

Comment: I know it says to avoid +1 comments, but seriously thank you good sir